# Flexsurvreg - applying covariates

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I am using `flexsurvreg` from the `flexsurv` package in order to fit a Gompertz model to survival data. An example of this with one categorical and one continuous covariate on each parameter is below:

```
library(survival)
library(flexsurv)
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex + shape(ph.ecog), 
data = lung, dist = "gompertz")

Estimates: 
                data mean  est        L95%       U95%       se         exp(est)     L95%       U95%     
shape                  NA   0.000659  -0.000210   0.001527   0.000443         NA         NA         NA
rate                   NA   0.003355   0.002042   0.005512   0.000850         NA         NA         NA
sex              1.396476  -0.525441  -0.852719  -0.198163   0.166982   0.591294   0.426254   0.820236
shape(ph.ecog)   0.951542   0.000937   0.000375   0.001498   0.000287   1.000937   1.000375   1.001500

N = 227,  Events: 164,  Censored: 63
Total time at risk: 69522
Log-likelihood = -1139.932, df = 4
AIC = 2287.864


par$coefficients
shape          rate          sex            shape(ph.ecog) 
0.0006588492  -5.6973226550  -0.5254411364   0.0009368314
```

Note, the difference between the rate terms in the summary and the `par$coefficients` call is that the latter is shown as the natural logarithm of the former

From the vignette - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/flexsurv.pdf - the Gompertz Hazard function is defined as -

```
Gompertz distribution with shape parameter a and rate parameter b has hazard function H(x: a, b) = b.e^{ax}
```

My question is, how are the covariates applied to the shape and rate parameters to derive the new hazard function?

Would the new shape parameter be `shape_new = shape + ph.ecog_value(between 1-5)*shape(ph.ecog) = 0.0006588492 + (some value between 1 and 5)*0.0009368314` and the new rate be `rate_new = rate + sex = -5.6973226550 - 0.5254411364` (as per the variables in my prior example)?

Note - this prior question is relevant, however, it did not concern the inclusion of covariates on the shape/rate parameters -[Gompertz Aging analysis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718566/gompertz-aging-analysis-in-r/18752600#18752600)